# App Engine Create and Email audio file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, audio, attachment

I need to create an audio file from an array of bytes(posted in by a mobile app) and then email it as an attachment in app engine (Java). Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send an audio file as an email attachment for some audio types (see the [list of supported formats](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html#Attachments)).
You can use a code like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

try {
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("user@example.com", "Mr. User"));
    msg.setSubject("My subject");

    String htmlBody;        // ...
    byte[] attachmentData;  // your audio file as an array of bits

    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

    MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");
    mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

    MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachment.setFileName("myfile.mp3"); // we will use mp3 as an example
    DataSource src = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachmentData, "audio/mpeg");
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(src));
    mp.addBodyPart(attachment);

    msg.setContent(mp);
    Transport.send(msg);

} catch (AddressException e) {
    // ...
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I get an exception when i use that code (javax.mail.MessagingException: Converting attachment data failed)

Comment: I corrected the code to use a `DataHandler` and a `ByteArrayDataSource` using this [Google Group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/e4bc13e091ba2e26/a54e006f0fda4a7e?#a54e006f0fda4a7e). Can you try it and tell me if it works, please?